# how can I prevent the user leaving the page when hitting the browser back button in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, browser, browser-history

Just wondering.

I have a page in Jquery Mobile which uses a popup that opens as a fullscreen page on smartphone displays:

Desktop/Tablet:

[image]

Smartphone:

[image]

Problem is, if the user views the page on smartphone, this looks like a real page. When the user hits the "back" button I provide, I'm just closing the popover. However, if the user hits the browser back button, he's leaving the page, because he never went a page down in the history.

**Question:**
Since I can't disable the browser back button, is there another way to create a browser history entry when the popover opens, so when the user presses the back button, I'm simply closing the popover and the browser history is back on the initial page vs. going "-1". If there are other workarounds to achieve this I'd also appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to open a new window like this - could it be done in some sort of lightbox?

Comment: hm. It's not opening in a new window. I'm just setting the popover dimensions to fullscreen and z-index it above the page, which is the problem. If it was a stand-alone page, it would have a browser history entry. But as popover it doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe what you can do is add the popover as a dialog page if the webpage is opened from a smartphone (you can use user-agent to check for this). You might want to check [`http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html`](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html) That way it will be added to the browser history.

Comment: ja. thinking about something like this, too. Somehow I need to create a browser entry... although this sounds like work, because I will also have to deal with JQMs urlHistory... thanks for the tip tough

Comment: in addition, you can also set the `data-rel="back"` of the back button you provided so that it will simulate the actual back behavior of jquery mobile, that way, you do not need to manually implement the default Back behavior of jquery mobile for your custom back button.

Comment: Good point. So I only need a "forward transition" when the popover opens. Thinking about that.

Comment: May I know what you mean by "forward transition"? Are you looking for a way to open the popover as a dialog?

Comment: no, i don't want to open it as a dialog, but if i use a back btn with data-rel "back", i need to do some kind of forward transition when opening the popover. otherwise clicking the back btn will go to -1 in the browser history (leaving the page).

Comment: May I know which popup you are using? If you can, please provide a link to the plugin.

Comment: It's my own plugin, see [here](https://github.com/frequent/multiview). The difference to JQMs popup is that my popovers may contain full JQM pages, so you can navigate around inside the popover. This all works well except (JQM navigation & urlHistory) except when opening the popover. I'm still kind of reluctant to add a history entry for the opening popover, because it took forever to align the popover navigation with JQM and I'm not sure if adding an "opening" entry causes more havoc than help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a live Vclick.

or

you could try disabling the class ui,

Example:

class="ui-disabled"

Comment: Wrong button. My button on the screenshot is ok. I'm refering to the browser back button, which can't be disabled.